# Newbie in SQL. Fetch messages and unprocessed endpoints

Tags: sql

I need the message ids and endpoints of messages from whom endpoints in multicast_message_recovery_processed is not in the list of endpoints of the multicast_endpoints table, for a given prcs_id, prcs_run_id, multicast_id.

Data -

**multicast_endpoints**

```
prcs_id prcs_run_id multicast_id endpoint_id

100     1           multiX       destA

100     1           multiX       destB

100     1           multiX       destC

100     1           multiX       destD

100     1           multiY       destX

100     1           multiY       destY
```

**multicast_message_recovery_processed**

```
prcs_id prcs_run_id multicast_id message_id endpoint_id

100     1           multiX       1          destA

100     1           multiX       2          destB

100     1           multiX       1          destC

100     1           multiY       1          destX
```

For a given `prcs_id = 100, prcs_run_id = 1, multicast_id = multiX`, the query should return:

```
1 destB
1 destD
2 destA
2 destC
2 destD
```

This essentially means that message 1 has not reached `destB` and `destD` while message 2 has not reached `destA`, `destC` and `destD`.

```
 CREATE TABLE multicast_message_recovery_processed
    (
      prcs_id character varying NOT NULL,
      prcs_run_id bigint NOT NULL,
      multicast_id character varying NOT NULL,
      message_id bigint,
      endpoint_id character varying NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT multicast_message_recovery_processed_pkey PRIMARY KEY (prcs_id , prcs_run_id , multicast_id , endpoint_id )
    )

    CREATE TABLE multicast_endpoints
    (
      prcs_id character varying NOT NULL,
      prcs_run_id bigint NOT NULL,
      multicast_id character varying NOT NULL,
      endpoint_id character varying NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT multicast_endpoints_pkey PRIMARY KEY (prcs_id , prcs_run_id , multicast_id , endpoint_id )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this looks ugly and there is probably a better way to write this, however, I think it works, and hopefully it'll be a starting point for you to improve on:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.message_id, e.endpoint_id AS endpoint_id
FROM dbo.multicast_endpoints e CROSS JOIN dbo.multicast_message_recovery_processed p
     LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT p.message_id, p.endpoint_id AS process_endpoint_id, e.endpoint_id AS endpoint_id
      FROM dbo.multicast_endpoints e CROSS JOIN dbo.multicast_message_recovery_processed p
      WHERE  e.prcs_id = p.prcs_id  AND  e.prcs_run_id = p.prcs_run_id AND e.multicast_id = p.multicast_id 
      AND p.endpoint_id = e.endpoint_id
     ) t ON p.message_id = t.message_id AND e.endpoint_id = t.endpoint_id
WHERE  e.prcs_id = p.prcs_id  AND  e.prcs_run_id = p.prcs_run_id AND e.multicast_id = p.multicast_id 
  AND e.prcs_id = '100' AND e.prcs_run_id = 1 AND e.multicast_id = 'MultiX' AND t.message_id IS NULL
ORDER BY message_id
```

Comment: Thanks Bassam. Can you please help me understand the query? To start with, why was the cross join in the nested block is required?

Comment: Run the inner query by itself first, and see what it'll give you. You will notice that when a message has reached a destination there will be a record in this query like this [1 destA destA] we are joining again to the same query and then selecting the messages that don't have that record, I am probably doing a poor job explaining, but the best way for you to understand it, is to break it down in pieces and see what each piece gives you, then hopefully you will understand how it's all working together

Comment: Yes. I did break down the query. Read about cross join and other joins. Your explanation did help "..when a message has reached a destination there will be a record in this query like this [1 destA destA] we are joining again to the same query and then selecting the messages that don't have that record.." Thanks a ton. :-)

Comment: @Narita glad you played with it until you understood it and not just used it, that's the only why you get better at SQL :)